# Is there a way to set ASP.NET TextBox password char when in Password TextMode?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, passwords, char

I want that when the user types in text, it should show • rather than a simple asterisk, is there a way (in win-forms' TextBox there is a property PasswordChar, what is it's similar in web)????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is browser specific. Maybe you could fake this with javascript, but I wouldn't recommend it.