# How to use PasswordChar in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, passwords

In windows forms applications, I use **PasswordChar** to set other characters in TextBox Password Field.

```
textBox1.PasswordChar = '*';
```

I don't think asp .net has `PasswordChar` property. What can I use instead?

Comment: this has been asked many times... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053940/is-there-a-way-to-set-asp-net-textbox-password-char-when-in-password-textmode, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540953/how-to-set-passwordchar-property-to-asp-net-textbox/17542689

Comment: You have to use javascript for this. see this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540953/how-to-set-passwordchar-property-to-asp-net-textbox/17542689

Answer (score 1):

The password field is rendered natively by the browser.You Can't do this .

Read this  [change password char in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257053/change-password-char-in-html)